# 1 letter amino acid variant to 3 letter

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to replace one letter AA variant to 3 letter code (for more easy reading).Everything works perfect but, few errors. Below is my code with comments. Thank you

```
x <- c("p.G12C","p.F121S","p.P124S","p.P124L","p.E13D",
        "p.E203K","p.Q209P","p.Q209P","p.Q209L")

aa3 <- c("Ala", "Arg", "Asn", "Asp", "Cys", "Glu", "Gln", "Gly", "His",
           "Ile", "Leu", "Lys", "Met", "Phe", "Pro", "Ser", "Thr", "Trp",
           "Tyr", "Val")
aa1 <- c("A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", "I", "L", "K",
           "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V")

for (i in 1:length(aa1))
{
  xy <- gsub(aa1[i],aa3[i],x,ignore.case = F)
}
```

Output

```
# Note that E, F and Q have unusual 3 letter replacement. 
  I could not figure out what is causing this.  
xy
[1] "p.Gly12Cys"    "p.Prohe121Ser" "p.Pro124Ser"   "p.Pro124Leu" 
    "p.Glylu13Asp"  "p.Glylu203Lys" "p.Glyln209Pro" "p.Glyln209Pro" "p.Glyln209Leu"
```

Expected output

```
"p.Gly12Cys"    "p.Phe121Ser" "p.Pro124Ser"   "p.Pro124Leu"   "p.Glu13Asp" 
"p.Glu203Lys" "p.Gln209Pro" "p.Gln209Pro" "p.Gln209Leu"
```

Error

```
outputs "p.Prohe121Ser"instead of "p.Phe121Ser" 
"p.Glylu13Asp" instead of  "p.Glu13Asp"
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your result.

Comment: your error occurs because in `aa1`, for example, `G` (`Gly`) is preceded by `Q` (`Gln`), so `Q` gets subbed with `Gln` and then `G` is spotted and gets replaced by `Gly`, so you get stuff like `Glyln`.

Comment: Hi @stasg. Thank you. yeah, I see your point. So, it is basically doing a substitution every time irrespective of the match.

Comment: @user5249203 yes, you are subbing the stuff that you've already subbed thus creating weird combinations

Comment: @user5249203 Sorry, didn't check the results earlier.  I thought `mgsub` should work.  Probably, there is some bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `mgsub`

```
library(qdap)
mgsub(aa1, aa3, x)
#[1] "p.Gly12Cys"    "p.Phe121Ser"   "p.Pro124Ser"   "p.Pro124Leu"  
#[5] "p.Glu13Alasp"  "p.Glu203Leuys" "p.Gln209Pro"   "p.Gln209Pro"  
#[9] "p.Gln209Leu"
```

#### Update

```
 d1 <- read.csv(text=sub('(..)(.)(\\d+)(.)', '\\1,\\2,\\3,\\4', x), 
          header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 d1[c(2,4)] <- lapply(d1[,c(2,4)], function(x) aa3[match(x, aa1)])
 do.call(paste0, d1)
 #[1] "p.Gly12Cys"  "p.Phe121Ser" "p.Pro124Ser" "p.Pro124Leu" "p.Glu13Asp" 
 #[6] "p.Glu203Lys" "p.Gln209Pro" "p.Gln209Pro" "p.Gln209Leu"
```

---

Or using `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn('[A-Z]', setNames(as.list(aa3), aa1), x)
#[1] "p.Gly12Cys"  "p.Phe121Ser" "p.Pro124Ser" "p.Pro124Leu" "p.Glu13Asp" 
#[6] "p.Glu203Lys" "p.Gln209Pro" "p.Gln209Pro" "p.Gln209Leu"
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, Thank you for the `mgsub` function. I was not aware of it. But, If you look closely on your output you can see what my issue is `"p.Glu13Alasp"` and `"p.Glu203Leuys"`. It is supposed to be `p.Glu13Asp` and `p.Glu203Lys`. I don't understand what causing this

Comment: @user5249203 Please update your post with the expected output

Comment: @user5249203 see my comment to your question for reason

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers. Akrun, gsubfn is short and easy. amazing.

Answer (score 5):

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(x, 
            c(
              "A"="Ala", "R"="Arg", "N"="Asn", "D"="Asp",
              "C"="Cys", "E"="Glu", "Q"="Gln", "G"="Gly",
              "H"="His", "I"="Ile", "L"="Leu", "K"="Lys",
              "M"="Met", "F"="Phe", "P"="Pro", "S"="Ser",
              "T"="Thr", "W"="Trp", "Y"="Tyr", "V"="Val"
              )    
            )
```

Answer (score 4):

here is a base R solution:

```
ref <- aa3
names(ref) <- aa1
tmp <- do.call(rbind, regmatches(x, regexec("p\\.([A-Z])([0-9]+)([A-Z])", x)))
tmp2 <- apply(tmp[, c(2, 4)], 2, FUN = function(x) ref[x])
paste0("p.", tmp2[, 1], tmp[, 3], tmp2[, 2])
#[1] "p.Gly12Cys"  "p.Phe121Ser" "p.Pro124Ser" "p.Pro124Leu" "p.Glu13Asp"  "p.Glu203Lys" "p.Gln209Pro" "p.Gln209Pro" "p.Gln209Leu"
```

you basically split your strings into constituting parts, e.g. `"p.Q209L"` is split into `p.`, `Q`, `209` and `L`. you then swap the amino acid one letter representations with their 3-letter versions using the reference vector, or using akrun's approach one can do away with `ref[x]` (and two additional lines!) and use `aa3[match(x, aa1)]` instead. then glue stuff back together.

Comment: I just finished the code of the same approach. This is the right answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)


repx1 <- function(x)
{
    str_replace_all(x, c("A"="Ala", "C"="Cys", "G"="Gly","H"="His", "I"="Ile", "L"="Leu", "M"="Met",  "P"="Pro", "S"="Ser","T"="Thr", "V"="Val"))
}


repx2 <- function(x)
{
    str_replace_all(x, c("R"="Arg","N"="Asn", "D"="Asp","E"="Glu", "Q"="Gln", "K"="Lys","F"="Phe","W"="Trp", "Y"="Tyr"))
}

'p.Q307R' %>% repx2 %>% repx2
```